# Is an internet access required when using conan?

Tags: c++, boost, package, artifactory, conan

In our organization, we use conan for our c++ package management. We have our local artifactory server which is acting as our remote for day-to-day usage. When we use a new package, we normally first download it from one of the global conan servers and upload it to our local server. I thought that this way we can work with stations that are not connected to the internet or that the connection is less stable there.

However, I encountered an issue with some of the packages. In specific, when I tried to use `boost/1.68.0@conan/stable` (that was downloaded and installed on our local artifactory server in the past) I received the following error:

```
ERROR: Error 403 downloading file https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.68.0/source/boost_1_68_0.tar.gz
Waiting 5 seconds to retry...
ERROR: boost/1.68.0@conan/stable: Error in source() method, line 75
     tools.get(url, sha256=sha256)
     ConanException: Error 403 downloading file https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.68.0/source/boost_1_68_0.tar.gz
```

After verifying that my remote is only the local artifactory server (by using `conan remote list`) - I have searched the dl.bintray.com in the mentioned conan package's folder. I found it in the recipe file: `~/.conan/data/boost/1.68.0/conan/stable/export/conanfile.py` in the following function:

```
    def source(self):
        if tools.os_info.is_windows:
            sha256 = "3b1db0b67079266c40b98329d85916e910bbadfc3db3e860c049056788d4d5cd"
            extension = ".zip"
        else:
            sha256 = "da3411ea45622579d419bfda66f45cd0f8c32a181d84adfa936f5688388995cf"
            extension = ".tar.gz"

        zip_name = "%s%s" % (self.folder_name, extension)
        url = "https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/%s/source/%s" % (self.version, zip_name)
        tools.get(url, sha256=sha256)
```

I thought that the location of the package & the download is managed by conan. Specifying the system to download from another hard-coded location quite miss the point for package management system - doesn't it? Is it a problem with the boost package? Am I using it wrong?

Thanks

Comment: yes, most recipes don't include the source code for a package and download it when building. If you ensure your artifactory contains all the built packages you need then users of your artifactory won't need to build them themselves and therefore won't need internet access to download the sources

Comment: A few suggestions: 1) public open source packages from ConanCenter no longer use ``user/channel``. Do not use ``boost/1.68.0@conan/stable``, that is legacy and unmantained, use ``boost/version`` https://conan.io/center/boost 2) Boost itself has changed their download center (https://www.boost.org/users/download/) 3) For full self-contained infra, forking ``conan-center-index`` repo and changing ``conandata.yml`` files to point to your own copy of the third party sources would be probably the recommended approach.

Comment: @drodri omg thank you. Why is this not more clearly stated anywhere!